Biholomorphic maps on projective variety
Let $X$ be a projective variety, and suppose it comes with some embedding $X\subset \mathbb{P}^n$. If $f:X\to X$ is biholomorphic, can we say anything like:f is the restriction to $X$ of some biholomorphic map on $\mathbb{P}^n$?
Thank you!

It is true if and only if the embedding is given by an f-invariant very ample line bundle.

Thanks for your comment. Why is this true, or when can I find a reference?

An embedding $i: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ comes with a line bundle $\mathcal{O}_X(1) := \mathcal{O}(1)_{|X}$ and global sections $i^* x_i$ that generate $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$.
If we have a biholomophic map $\phi: \mathbb{P}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ then $\phi^*\mathcal{O}(1) = \mathcal{O}(1)$. This same property will hold for $\phi$ restricted to $X$. Therefore, if $f^* \mathcal{O}_X(1) \neq \mathcal{O}_X(1)$, then $f$ cannot come from a map $\phi$.
An example of this is the map $f: \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ with swaps the two factors and $i$ the embedding given by $\mathcal{O}_X(1,2)$. Since $f^* \mathcal{O}(1,2) = \mathcal{O}(2,1)$, $f$ does not come from a map of the projective space.
